# python pandas apply function in groupby, and add results as column in data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

IM practicing with sample data to learn pandas.  I have sample data like the following:

| symbol | date_time | close | volume |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XOM | 2021-04-13 13:00:00 | 56.5 | 10000 |
| XOM | 2021-04-13 13:01:00 | 57.5 | 10000 |
| XOM | 2021-04-13 13:02:00 | 56.25 | 10000 |
| XOM | 2021-04-13 13:03:00 | 58.5 | 10000 |
| AAPL | 2021-04-13 13:00:00 | 135.6 | 10000 |
| AAPL | 2021-04-13 13:01:00 | 137.5 | 10000 |
| AAPL | 2021-04-13 13:02:00 | 136.25 | 10000 |
| AAPL | 2021-04-13 13:03:00 | 138.5 | 10000 |

I used the groupby function on symbol and close price to add some simple moving averages using panda.rolling.mean functions.

Now I'd like to us talib to calcuate the RSI, for each symbol.  I thought I could use an apply and call a function.  I see the output when I print the np array, however, Im not seeing the column added.

```
quote_data.groupby("sym")["close"].apply(calc_rsi).reset_index(name='rsi_test')


def calc_rsi(series):
    rsi_arr=np.array(series)
    RSI = talib.RSI(rsi_arr, timeperiod=14)
    #print(RSI) --> produces valid output
    return(RSI)
```

Sample Numpy array output is below, and first 14 values are nan which is expected.

```
         nan         nan         nan         nan         nan         nan
         nan         nan 17.10526316 30.8277027  38.64107884 36.42559842
 35.98126419 49.82352931 51.12420941 56.4889558  53.50561034 57.38372096
 63.24414699 65.34066328 65.70388628 60.26289822 61.54881365 61.54881365
```

Comment: What is your "Sample Numpy array output" referring to? Is it the result of `calc_rsi`?

Comment: Yes, sorry if that wasnt clear.  If I do a print(type(RSI)) in the calc_rsi function, it returns ```<class 'numpy.ndarray'>```

Comment: i think you are just doing the calculation but not actually adding the result to the dataframe. perhaps try: quote_data['RSI'] = quote_data.groupby("sym")["close"].apply(calc_rsi)

Comment: @JonathanLeon I tried that, and I see the RSI column is added, but the values are all NaN

Comment: Issue could be something to do with the indexing.  The counts match, the original dataframe has a 1130 entries, 0 to 1129.  Because I did the group by, the RSI arrays are 564 and 566 in length, so the total count matches, but perhaps the indexes are off?

Comment: it may be RSI isn't a pandas series??? try converting np array to series? if you are seeing valid RSI values then it's something with how pandas is reading that data into the dataframe. or just pass the pandas seriers to talib instead of creating the array first. Not sure exactly...but some things to try.

Comment: It works fine to pass to rsi with one symbol, but if more than one symbol in data frame the calculations are off when it hits next symbol, because it uses last 14 values, hence why i need the group by to work

Comment: Ok, i tried this in the function
    
    rsi_series=pd.Series(RSI)
    return(rsi_series)

Again, data prints fine, the series is good, it prints one series of RSI values for each symbol, I just can't get it back into the data frame, still shows NaN.

Answer (score 1):

It was index related.

setting the series index before passing it back works:

```
quote_data['rsi'] = quote_data.groupby("sym")["close"].apply(calc_rsi)

def calc_rsi(series):
    rsi_arr=np.array(series)
    RSI = talib.RSI(rsi_arr, timeperiod=14)
    rsi_series=pd.Series(RSI,series.index)
    #print(rsi_series.size)
    return(rsi_series)
```